# LSTM model has lower than expected accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

**Hello, I am working on the resolution of a problem that has to do with time series.**

I am plotting y = sin (x) with 10000 values

Then, to each value (y), I associate an index calculated based on the next values (between 0 and 1)

- if the next 150 values are lower than the current one, then this index will be set to 1
- If the next 150 values are higher then the current one, then this index will be set to 0

Then I'm trying to set up a LSTM network using tensorflow/keras in order to predict this index based on the last 150 values, which should be pretty trivial for a sinus function.

Here is the code and the explanation :

1. I make an array with 10000 values of sin(x)

```
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 10000

array = np.array([math.sin(i*0.02) for i in range(1, n)])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([(i*0.02) for i in range(1, n)], array, linewidth=0.75)
plt.show()
```

2. Calculate the associated index, here SELL_INDEX

```
SELL_INDEX = np.zeros((len(array), 1))

for index, row in enumerate(array):
    
    if index > len(array) - 150:
        continue

    max_price = np.amax(array[index:index + 150])
    min_price = np.amin(array[index:index + 150])
    
    current_sell_index = (row - min_price) / (max_price - min_price)
    
    SELL_INDEX[index][0] = current_sell_index

data_with_sell_index = np.hstack((array.reshape(-1,1), SELL_INDEX))
data_final =  np.hstack( (data_with_sell_index,  np.arange(len(data_with_sell_index)).reshape(-1, 1)) )
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(data_final[:,2], data_final[:,0] , c = data_final[:,1], s = .5)
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot (sin(x), SELL_INDEX : 1 being yellow, 0 being purple )

[image: sinus with the previously calculated index, 1 being yellow, 0 being blue]

3. Here is the creation of the model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.python.keras import models, Input, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
# from neural_intelligence.batches_generator import generate_smart_lstm_batch, get_smart_lstm_data

class LearningRateReducerCb(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        old_lr = self.model.optimizer.lr.read_value()
        new_lr = old_lr * 0.99
        print("\nEpoch: {}. Reducing Learning Rate from {} to {}".format(epoch, old_lr, new_lr))
        self.model.optimizer.lr.assign(new_lr)


# Model creation

input_layer = Input(shape=(150, 1))
layer_1_lstm = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
dropout_1 = Dropout(0.0)(layer_1_lstm)
layer_2_lstm = LSTM(200, return_sequences=True)(dropout_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.0)(layer_2_lstm)
layer_3_lstm = LSTM(100)(dropout_2)

output_sell_index_proba = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layer_3_lstm)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_sell_index_proba)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

4. Training the model

```
def generate_batch(dataset_x, dataset_y, sequence_length):
    x_data, y_data = [], []
    for i in range(len(list(zip(dataset_x, dataset_y))) - sequence_length - 1):
        x_data.append(dataset_x[i:i + sequence_length])
        y_data.append(dataset_y[i + sequence_length])
    return np.array(x_data), np.array(y_data)

x, y = generate_batch(data_final[:,0], data_final[:,1], sequence_length=150)
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1)
y = y.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, 1)

print(x.shape, y.shape)

model.fit(x, y, callbacks=[LearningRateReducerCb()], epochs=2,
                   validation_split=0.1, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
```

Here is my issue, the accuracy never goes above 0.52, I don't understand why, everything seems to be ok to me.

This should be very simple for such a powerful tool as LSTM, but it can figure out what the index could be.

If you could me help in any way, you're welcome, thank you

EDIT : To plot the result, use

```
data = np.array(data_final[:,0])
results = np.array([])
for i in range (150, 1000):
    result = model.predict(data[i - 150 : i].reshape(1, 150, 1))
    results = np.append(result, results)
        
data = data[150:1000]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([range(len(data))], data.flatten() , c = results.flatten(), s= 1)
plt.show()
```

It seems to be working, the issue is : why is the accuracy never goes up while training ?

This leads me to investigate on what was the problem instead of trying predicting

Comment: Are you able to plot your model predictions to give a visual clue?

Comment: Also, where can I install neural_intelligence please

Comment: It looks like you mean to call your defined function `generate_batch` rather than `generate_smart_lstm_batch`.  Would you please confirm (I edited your code to reflect this)

Comment: I edited the post in order to add the plotting result sections, its very surprising cause it seems to be working, but why the accuracy is stuck a 0.5. i must do something wrong somewhere or using the wrong metrics

Comment: Have a read of this to see if it helps (idk) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53361746/2069472

Comment: This may be simplistic, but to my mind you are only accurately predicting half your curve.  This is where the blue and yellow lines overlap in your fit chart.  The accuracy measure will be computed over all of the rows unless you tell it otherwise.  This intuitively explains why your accuracy is c. 50%.  You should be able to confirm this by splitting your data into these two portions and calculating the accuracy on each

Comment: It seems to be exactly the problem, i still don't fully understand it, I will go deeper into it. You can post as an answer if you wish to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be simplistic, but to my mind you are only accurately predicting half your curve.

- This is where the blue and yellow lines overlap in your fit chart. The accuracy measure will be computed over all of the rows unless you tell it otherwise.
- This intuitively explains why your accuracy is c. 50%. You should be able to confirm this by splitting your data into these two portions and calculating the accuracy on each

I suggest playing around with your features and transformations to understand which type of shapes predict your sine curve with a higher accuracy (and give a fuller overlap between the lines).